# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to record audio in my Piano app in android studio using `MediaRecorder`. After searching for answers on how to save the file as `getExternalPublicDirectory` is deprecated so i used `context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();` . Now when i run the app and hit the record button , i get this error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)` in the line `mediaRecorder.prepare();` .. Please Help!!

```
private void startRecording() throws IOException {

        try {
            String path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
            audioFile = new File(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Tag", "external storage access error " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }


        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

         mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());

            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)` is what expected since the path that you're providing to `setOutputFile()` points **to a directory** and not a file to save the recorded data.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setOutputFile(java.lang.String)) is clear,

> Sets the path of the output file to be produced.

Try and fix your path,

```
String dirPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = direPath + "/recording";          
audioFile = new File(filePath);
```